# Probability that out of $m$ people exactly $n$ have their birthday on a pre-determined day (e.g. the 1st of January)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification

My first instinct was that this is given by the binomial distribution, i.e. if $p=\frac{1}{365}$ is the probability that a person has their birthday on January $1$st, then the probability that exactly $n$ out of $m$ people have their birthday on January $1$st is given by the probability of $n$ successes in $m$ experiments, i.e. by $\binom{m}{n}p^n(1-p)^{m-n}$, but now I'm wondering if this isn't simply the probability that these $n$ people share a birthday, never mind on what day it falls. Am I correct in doubting myself or was my initial solution the right one?

Edit: In addition to this, I am also supposed to calculate the Poisson approximation of this probability (for $m\to\infty$, I assume $-$ it's not really stated clearly in the exercise). Now I know that the Poisson distribution gives the limiting behaviour of binomial distributions when $mp_m\to\lambda$, but I am unsure of how to proceed in this case, since regardless of the number $m$, the probability $p$ stays the same. Should I just set $p_m=\frac{1}{m}$ and calculate that way?

Comment: @ShootingStars I'm afraid I don't catch your meaning.

Comment: The correct answer is given by the binomial distribution (which you have written incorrectly in your post).

Comment: @MikeEarnest woops, you're right, I corrected the exponent. But, in any case, how do I convince myself that this really is the correct answer?

Comment: @V.Ch. ignore the comment, sorry about that

Comment: Your answer is correct, and you can see this by how you defined $p$. It's the same for everybody, dependant on just one person at a time. If you were calculating the probability that $n$ people shared a birthday, then you have a lot more dependance, and multiplying $p$ a bunch of times makes less sense.

Comment: For the Poisson approximation, do not let $m \to \infty$ for fixed $n$, as that limit is clearly $0$.  Instead find the expected number of people with that birthday which is  $\frac m{365}$ here, and then find the Poisson probably for $n$ events given that mean as the parameter of the Poisson distribution

Comment: @Henry so if one has a binomial distribution with parameters $n,p$ and one is supposed to calculate the Poisson approximation (i.e. no sequence of binomial distributions is actually given), one should simply take $\lambda=np$? What's the logic behind this?

Comment: Clearly the mean is correct but the variance and probability mass function are wrong.  But you know there is convergence in probability as $n$ increases and $\lambda=np$ is constant, so at some stage the argument is that the approximation may be *reasonable* for large $n$ and small $p$